# Sort a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

I know that this topic has been already discussed but I can't solve looking other answers, so sorry in advance for my ripetion!

I need to sort this Dictionary by keys

```
codeValueDict = ["us": "$", "it": "€", "fr": "€"]
```

so I need a dictionary like this

```
sortedDict = ["fr": "€", "it": "€", "us": "$"]
```

but I can't do that.

I tried this

```
let sortedKeysAndValues = sorted(dictionary) { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

but after I need to create two arrays from this dictionary (keys and values) and, using that solution

```
codesArray = sortedKeysAndValues.keys.array
```

give me the error *'[(String, String)]' does not have a member named 'keys'* because that solution doesn't return exactly a dictionary.

So i tried another solution:

```
    let prova = codiceNomeDict as NSDictionary
    for (k,v) in (Array(codiceNomeDict).sorted {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
        let value = "[\"\(k)\": \"\(v)\"]"
        println(value)
    }
```

Which works good but then I don't know how create a new dictionary of *value*s.

What's the best solution? How to make it works?

Comment: You need to go back to what problem you're trying to solve. In your example, `codeValueDict` and `sortedDict` are exactly the same dictionary (so when you say "I need a dictionary like this," you have one). The point you need to address is what you're trying to sort. Do you mean that you want to enumerate over the values in a specific order, or do you mean you want a string representation in a specific order, or something else? What's the output of this function supposed to be? There is no such thing as an "ordered dictionary." It doesn't mean anything in Swift.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The output of `sorted` function above is an **Array**. So you cannot get keys & values like a **Dictionary**. But you can use `map` function to retrieve those sorted keys & values

> Return an Array containing the sorted elements of `source`{according}.
>   The sorting algorithm is not stable (can change the relative order of
>   elements for which isOrderedBefore does not establish an order).

```
let codeValueDict = ["us": "$", "it": "€", "fr": "€"]

let sortedArray = sorted(codeValueDict, {$0.0 < $1.0})
print(sortedArray)

let keys = sortedArray.map {return $0.0 }
print(keys)

let values = sortedArray.map {return $0.1 }
print(values)
```

Comment: Just a note that In Swift 2, sorted is now sort and the old sort is now sortInPlace, and both are to be called on the array itself (they were previously global functions) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738793/sorted-function-in-swift-2

Answer (score 6):

Dictionaries are not ordered. If you want to enumerate over them in order, you can do that using @HoaParis's solution (which is my preference), or also

```
for (k,v) in sorted(codiceNomeDict, {$0.1 < $1.1}) { ... }
```

which is just a little better way than what you were doing before because it doesn't generate a temporary array.

But if you really want "a collection that maps one value to another and is ordered by its key" then you need to create some other data structure for that. So let's do that. It's a good learning experience.

This version just implements `SequenceType` and provides a get/set subscript, which is most of what you'd generally want. Making it a full `CollectionType` is a bit of a pain I think, since `startIndex` and `endIndex` hae to be O(1). Possible; just more than I want to do this morning.

Note the major addition of `Key: Comparable`. That's why `Dictionary` *can't* be ordered. There's no promise that you can sort their keys. By adding that requirement, we can.

```
struct SortedDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value where Key: Comparable>: SequenceType {
    private var dict: Dictionary<Key, Value>
    init(_ dict: Dictionary<Key, Value>) {
        self.dict = dict
    }
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<(Key, Value)> {
        let values = Array(zip(self.dict.keys, self.dict.values))
            .sorted {$0.0 < $1.0 }
        return GeneratorOf(values.generate())
    }
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get        { return self.dict[key] }
        set(value) { self.dict[key] = value }
    }
}

var codeValueDict = ["us": "$", "it": "€", "fr": "€"]
var sortedDict = SortedDictionary(codeValueDict)
for (k, v) in sortedDict {
    println("\(k) => \(v)")
}
sortedDict["us"]
sortedDict["ab"] = "!"
sortedDict
```

Why would you bother with `SortedDictionary` when you already have `sorted()`? Well, usually I wouldn't. But it does offer opportunities for abstraction. You could control sort order at object creation rather than at object enumeration. You could potentially cache the sort order (though I suspect in most cases that will hurt rather than help).

But I recommend just using `sorted` in general.

Answer (score 4):

Swift doesn't include a sorted dictionary type, and dictionaries cannot be sorted. You could add an extension that offers sorting to `[(Key, Value)]` by doing this:

```
extension Dictionary {

    func sort(isOrderedBefore: (Key, Key) -> Bool) -> [(Key, Value)] {
        var result: [(Key, Value)] = []
        let sortedKeys = keys.array.sorted(isOrderedBefore)
        for key in sortedKeys {
            result.append(key, self[key]!)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorting your keys by the dictionary's value is actually simpler than it appears at first:

```
let yourDict = ["One": "X", "Two": "B", "Three": "Z", "Four": "A"]
let sortedKeys = yourDict.keys.sort({ (firstKey, secondKey) -> Bool in
    return yourDict[firstKey] < yourDict[secondKey]
})
```

And that's it! There's really nothing more to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort dictionary in such easy way. I think dictionary is using some sort of tree data structure. But after sorting you get an array of tuples. So you can get keys in such way:

```
    let codeValueDict = ["us": "$", "it": "€", "fr": "€"]
    let sortedKeysAndValues = sorted(codeValueDict) { $0.0 < $1.0 }
    let keys = sortedKeysAndValues.map {$0.0 }
    let values = sortedKeysAndValues.map {$0.1 }
```

Comment: That's great! Do you know a way to sort by values instead keys?

Comment: replace `{ $0.0 < $1.0 }` by `{ $0.1 < $1.1 }` to sort by values

Answer (score 0):

### Sort keys case-insensitive in Swift 2

Here is a function which returns a **case-insensitive** sorted array of keys (or any String values).

Please keep in mind that Swift’s dictionary data structure can not be stored sorted by keys in memory. So yes, you can sort it by keys but if you print it for example then the key order is again random.

```
 /// returns an array of values sorted by values case-insensitive
func sortCaseInsensitive(values:[String]) -> [String]{

    let sortedValues = values.sort({ (value1, value2) -> Bool in

        if (value1.lowercaseString < value2.lowercaseString) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
    return sortedValues
}
```

Call with

```
    let dict = ["world": "Hello!", "foo": "bar", "zYeah": "a", "akey": "xval"]
    let sortedKeys = sortCaseInsensitive(Array(dict.keys))
```