# sorted function in Swift 2

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

I'm sorting an Array like this:

```
var users = ["John", "Matt", "Mary", "Dani", "Steve"]

func back (s1:String, s2:String) -> Bool
{
    return s1 > s2
}

sorted(users, back)
```

But I'm getting this error

> 'sorted' is unavailable: call the 'sort()' method on the collection

What should be the correct way to use the sort() method here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Follow what the error message is telling you, and call `sort` on the collection:

```
users.sort(back)
```

Note that in **Swift 2**, `sorted` is now `sort` and the old `sort` is now `sortInPlace`, and both are to be called on the array itself (they were previously global functions).

*Be careful, this has changed again in **Swift 3**, where `sort` is the mutating method, and `sorted` is the one returning a new array.*

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use closure is:

```
var numbers = [2,4,34,6,33,1,67,20]


var numbersSorted = numbers.sort( { (first, second ) -> Bool in

    return first < second
})
```

Comment: this results in values like - [1,10,100,2,20,200] But I am looking to get values like -[1,2,10,20,100]

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use closure in a simple way:

```
users.sort({a, b in a > b})
```

Answer (score 1):

In **swift 2.2** there are multiple ways we can use closures with sort function as follows.

Consider the array

```
var names:[String] = ["aaa", "ddd", "rrr", "bbb"];
```

The different options for sorting the array with swift closures are as added

**Option 1**

```
// In line with default closure format.
names = names.sort( { (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in return s1 < s2 })
print(names)
```

**Option 2**

```
// Omitted args types
names = names.sort( { s1, s2 in return s1 > s2 } )
print(names)
```

**Option 3**

```
// Omitted args types and return keyword as well
names = names.sort( { s1, s2 in s1 < s2 } )
print(names)
```

**Option 4**

```
// Shorthand Argument Names(with $ symbol)
// Omitted the arguments area completely.
names = names.sort( { $0 < $1 } )
print(names)
```

**Option 5**

This is the most simple way to use closure in sort function.

```
// With Operator Functions
names = names.sort(>)
print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
```

**Swift 2.3**

```
let sortedArray = array.sort()
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let sortedArray = array.sorted()
```