# .sort not working in Swift 2.0

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift2

I'm trying to sort my arrays of combinations i currently have. It is multidimensional array, but I only need to sort out the array that's inside for now.

```
for combination in myCombinations {
        combination.sort({$0 < $1})
        print("\(combination)")
    }
```

Here's my code to sort out the array and here's my result.

```
["lys", "dyt", "lrt"]
["lys", "dyt", "gbc"]
["lys", "dyt", "lbc"]
```

I also got a warning that says "Result of call to 'sort' is unused"
Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should override de sorted arrays in myCombinations. That should fix your issue and your warning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift 2, what was `sort` is now `sortInPlace` (and what was `sorted` is now `sort`), and both methods are to be called on the array itself (they were previously global functions).

When you call `combination.sort({$0 < $1})` you actually *return* a sorted array, you're not sorting the source array in place.

And in your example the result of `combination.sort({$0 < $1})` is not assigned to any variable, that's what the compiler is telling you with this error message.

Assign the result of `sort`:

```
let sortedArray = combination.sort({$0 < $1})
print(sortedArray)
```

---

If you want to get an array of sorted arrays, you can use `map` instead of a loop:

```
let myCombinations = [["lys", "dyt", "lrt"], ["lys", "dyt", "gbc"], ["lys", "dyt", "lbc"]]

let sortedCombinations = myCombinations.map { $0.sort(<) }

print(sortedCombinations)  // [["dyt", "lrt", "lys"], ["dyt", "gbc", "lys"], ["dyt", "lbc", "lys"]]
```

Comment: Best explanation I've seen!! Thank you.

Comment: *Be careful, this has [changed again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32738916/2227743) in **Swift 3**, where `sort` is the mutating method, and `sorted` is the one returning a new array.*