# Swift conversion between 1 to 2

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

Please I can not find a solution for this my problem converting Swift. Below entered my code and error.

My Code:

```
let sortedKeysAndValues = sort(dicVal) { $0.0 < $1.0 }

                                              ^
```

Error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

My Code:

```
let result = String(map(Array(sValori[i])) {$0 == "|" ? "," : $0})
```

Error:

> Missing argument label 'arrayLiteral:' in call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.sort not working in Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920814/sort-not-working-in-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Map and sort are no longer global functions in 2.0. You need to use them as `dicVal.sort(...)` or `Array(sValori[i]).map(...)`

Comment: Okay I try. Many Thanks