# Error with "sorted" in Swift 2.0

Tags: arrays, swift2

I really tried to make it work in every possible way but it is still not working: I copied from an older Swift tutorial so probably that is why but I haven't found anything online. (Beginner Student at Swift)

ERROR: it recommends to use `sort` but I can't make it work with that either.

```
let unsortedArray = [98,23,643,3,678,2,568,1,234,556,4]          
let sortedArray = sorted(unsortedArray, { (first : Int, second : Int) -> Bool in   
    return first < second  
})  
sortedArray
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `enter code here`?

Comment: About `sorted`, have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920814/sort-not-working-in-swift-2-0/32921271#32921271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sorted" is unavailable, so the error says to call `sort()` on the collection. It's built-in implementation is the basic "first < second" sorting you need. So, it's as simple as this:

```
    let unsortedArray = [98,23,643,3,678,2,568,1,234,556,4]

    let sortedArray = unsortedArray.sort()
```

Comment: Than this case Swift has changed a lot. Thx for the answer I would never think that, there can be such a simple solution.

Comment: Hi @Peta if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thx I will in the future :D