# Converting from Sorted method to Sort in Swift 2 (Xcode 7)

Tags: arrays, xcode, sorting, swift2

This function retrieves the array of item representation from disk, converts it to an array of TodoItem instances using an unnamed closure we pass to map, and sorts that array chronologically.
Sorted doesn't work anymore, I get an error to switch to sort. But I can't seem to get it right. Whatever I do results in various errors.

```
func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
        var todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:]
        let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)
        return items.map({TodoItem(deadline: $0["deadline"] as! NSDate, title: $0["title"] as! String, UUID: $0["UUID"] as! String!)}).sorted({(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
            (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .OrderedAscending)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `sorted` by `sort`, it *looks like* you've already done the rest of the translation (I can't check, not knowing how it was before):

```
func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
    var todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:]
    let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)
    return items.map( {TodoItem(deadline: $0["deadline"] as! NSDate, title: $0["title"] as! String, UUID: $0["UUID"] as! String!)} ).sort( {(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
        (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .OrderedAscending)
    })
}
```

Reminder: `sorted` has become `sort` and the old `sort` is now `sortInPlace`.

Comment: *Be careful, this has [changed again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32738916/2227743) in **Swift 3**, where `sort` is the mutating method, and `sorted` is the one returning a new array.*